# Why messages from a pipe are being displayed as a char at at time? In C language

Tags: c, linux, parent-child

I am trying to read messages sent from a child process to a parent using pipes. I asked question here and got some help and I was able to get the messages. But the problem is the messages are displayed one char at a time. I don't have any idea why. This my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf("\nWritten by Nawar Youssef\n");

    int i, x, fd_log[2], fd_A_B[2], pipe_size=500;
    char ch, message_from_A[pipe_size], message_from_B[pipe_size],
                        msg_to_log[pipe_size], msg_to_B[pipe_size];

    pipe(fd_log);
    pipe(fd_A_B);

    //fork process A
    if (fork()==0) { //child
        printf("Inside process A\n");
        for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            //creat new a record (C or D 0 to/or 9)
            x = (rand() % 2);
            if (x == 1)
                ch='C';
            else
                ch='D';

            //write msg to log pipe
            sprintf(msg_to_log, "A sent to B: %c %d\n", ch, i);
            printf("wirtten to log pipe--> %s\n", msg_to_log);
            close(fd_log[READ]);
            write(fd_log[WRITE], msg_to_log, strlen(msg_to_log)+1);
        }//end for()
        close(fd_log[WRITE]);
        _exit(1); //process A

    }
    else { //parent
        close(fd_log[WRITE]);
        while (read(fd_log[READ], message_from_A, strlen(msg_to_log)+1) > 0 ) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("\nIn log: msg from A: %s", message_from_A);
        }
        close(fd_log[READ]); //this line won't affect output 
    }
}
```

And the output like the following, if you notice, the characters are the forming the sentence: A sent to B: C 0, which is the wanted output but each char displayed on it own line!

In log: msg from A: Aь|?

In log: msg from A:  ь|?

In log: msg from A: sь|?

In log: msg from A: eь|?

In log: msg from A: nь|?

In log: msg from A: tь|?

In log: msg from A:  ь|?

In log: msg from A: tь|?

In log: msg from A: oь|?

In log: msg from A:  ь|?

In log: msg from A: Bь|?

In log: msg from A: :ь|?

In log: msg from A:  ь|?

In log: msg from A: Cь|?

In log: msg from A:  ь|?

In log: msg from A: 0ь|?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The read code uses:

```
read(fd_log[READ], message_from_A, strlen(msg_to_log)+1)
```

and in the parent, you've not initialized `msg_to_log` so you probably get 0 as the string length (mostly by accident; certainly not by design), and read one character at a time.  Don't use `strlen()` in the receiving code; use `sizeof()` — without the `+1`!

---

> I tried using `sizeof()` but it gave me only the first message, so the output was:
>
> ```
> In log: msg from A: A sent to B: C 0
> ```
>
> and then the program terminated

Like this?

```
$ ./piperead
Inside process A
written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 0

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: D 1

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 2

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 3

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 4

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 5

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: D 6

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: D 7

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 8

written to log pipe--> A sent to B: C 9

In log: msg from A: [[A sent to B: C 0
]]
In log: msg from A: [[A sent to B: C 8
]]
$
```

Except this has two reads, one for entries 0..7 and one for entries 8..9.

This is from a mildly modified version of your code.  The trouble is that you're writing the null bytes on the pipe, and the `read()` is reading multiple messages in a single operation, but the `printf()` stops at the first null byte.

Here's the output from an adapted version of your code:

```
$ ./piperead
Inside process A
0: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 0]]
1: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: D 1]]
2: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 2]]
3: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 3]]
4: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 4]]
5: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 5]]
6: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: D 6]]
7: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: D 7]]
8: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 8]]
9: written to log pipe--> [[A sent to B: C 9]]
In log: msg from A: 85: 16: [[A sent to B: C 0]]
In log: msg from A: 85: 16: [[A sent to B: C 5]]
$
```

Note that the read operations both got 85 bytes of data, but only the first 16 (17) were visible as the string printed by `printf()`.  The division of the data in the pipe depends on lots of factors.  This was run on a machine with 6 CPUs.  I ran it other times and got all 170 bytes read in a single operation; I also got a 119:51 split, and 136:34 (which is what was shown in the first example), and any other n*17:(10-n)*17 ratio is possible too.

This is the revised source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { READ = 0, WRITE = 1 };

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int x;
    int fd_log[2];
    int pipe_size = 500;
    char ch;
    char message_from_A[pipe_size];
    char msg_to_log[pipe_size];

    pipe(fd_log);

    if (fork() == 0) // child
    {
        printf("Inside process A\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // creat new a record (C or D 0 to/or 9)
            x = (rand() % 2);
            if (x == 1)
                ch = 'C';
            else
                ch = 'D';

            // write msg to log pipe
            sprintf(msg_to_log, "A sent to B: %c %d", ch, i);
            printf("%d: written to log pipe--> [[%s]]\n", i, msg_to_log);
            write(fd_log[WRITE], msg_to_log, strlen(msg_to_log) + 1);
        } // end for()
        close(fd_log[READ]);
        close(fd_log[WRITE]);
        _exit(1); // process A
    }
    else // parent
    {
        int nbytes;
        close(fd_log[WRITE]);
        while ((nbytes = read(fd_log[READ], message_from_A, sizeof(message_from_A))) > 0)
        {
            printf("In log: msg from A: %d: %zu: [[%s]]\n", nbytes, strlen(message_from_A),
                   message_from_A);
            sleep(1);
        }
        close(fd_log[READ]); // this line won't affect output
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It would not be hard to revise the printing code to print all the strings in the buffer — a tad fiddly, but something that would be good for you to deal with.

Comment: I tired using sizeof() but it gave me only the first message, so the output was: In log: msg from A: A sent to B: C 0  and then the program terminated

Comment: Now I understand the problem and how it happens, but still confused about the solution. This is my first time working on something serious in C. I also played a little bit with the code and I am still stock with getting one char at a time, or only first line displayed. Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the problem?  In my code, you know how much data was read by `read()`, and you know that each string is terminated with a null byte, so you can step through the byte array, printing out strings until you've reached the end of the data read off the pipe; then you go back for more.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Last night I was so sleepy so my brain couldn't function well. Thanks for the help.